# Equipment to throttle energy consumption of 220V AC device (Solar+grid)

Tags: current-limiting, home-installation

*(This is my first post in this community, hoping it's the right place)*

I'm looking for a simple way to prevent a 2kW house water heater to draw too much current at once. Mostly because solar power seldom can provide that much (and the rest is taken from the grid). 300W would be perfect for me.
Of course I would couple it with a timer to draw only when power is available

I suppose there exists a simple device for that. Connected if possible. No luck in finding it online though.

And I'm also interested in any theoretic insights on how such a device will work, and its limitations (eg. if several loads are connected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root problem here is that OP does not have *net metering*, where the utility charges 14 cents a kWH for power consumed but credits 14 cents a kWH for solar power generated. Utilities ***hate*** net metering because of the [Duck Curve](https://www.energy.gov/eere/articles/confronting-duck-curve-how-address-over-generation-solar-energy).  They want to pay only 1-2 cents because of the general worthlessness of morning solar (at one point, California *paid* Arizona to take their surplus, since the reservoirs were dry and could not do pumped storage).

Given the anti-net-metering stand of the utility, you want to avoid selling power to the utility *then buying it back*.  Thus the goal of directing solar to a storage load.

### Is it net metering *within the measurement interval*?

If so, that's super easy.

But I don't believe this, and here's why. A typical house draws less than 100W most of the time, yet (in America) averages 1200W.  That's because you have many large 3-6kW large loads [banging on/off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bang%E2%80%93bang_control) at intervals, waking up, running for 5 minutes and quitting. One or another is running several times an hour, so most windows would see their solar gobbled up by one of those periodic loads. So functionally, *this would **still** be net metering*, and that's exactly what the utility is trying to get away from*.

But OK. What if it is net metering within the 15, 30 or 60 minute sampling window?

Well, then, it's easy. Pick a higher frequency than that (say: 5 minutes) and do slow-format PWM - for 10% duty cycle turn the heater on for 30 seconds every 5 minutes.  In any given 15 minute sampling window it'll have pulled 2000W for 1:30 and nothing for 13:50, exactly matching the 200W solar output in net.

You could use a contactor for that, but you could avoid all the clacking by simply using a triac and holding the triac open continuously for the ~30 second period.  No sinewave chopping necessary; no power factor concerns.

### If the meter is smarter than that...

A dimmer won't play with a quality meter (unless the power company wants to tolerate this). Already discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/674440/95888); let me hit the high points.  **Triac dimming is time-based**.  It sends power to the incandescent bulb *some of the time*.

[image]

So it's a 10 *millisecond* cycle instead of the 10 *minute* cycle in the straw-man above: **but it's exactly the same problem**. Electricity doesn't store for 10ms.   You would simply be selling 200W to the utility for 90% of the "meat of the sinewave" and buying 1800W for the 10%.

The good news is, the solar inverter will not be degraded by the lousy power factor of the PWM controlled water heater, since its lowest impedance coupling is to the grid itself.  The grid will see a weird PF, but whether that bothers them depends on how much the utility polices for that. I don't see them hunting you down for 2 kW :)

So what are the options?

### The off-grid method: Dump terminals

To start with, **off-grid solar** people have been doing *exactly this* for a good long time. They have DC string solar charge controllers with a set of terminals called "DUMP".  Excess solar that won't fit in the batteries gets fed out the DUMP terminals and they have a variety of ways to hook a water heater to that.  (Careful with the water heater's thermostat; it's not rated to interrupt DC.)

So in this case, you would need to add an off-grid solar charge controller to replace your grid-tie inverter, a "token" battery merely to get the charge controller to function, and then attach the water heater to the "Dump" terminals. When the water heater's thermostat calls for heat, you'd switch the solar array from being connected to the grid-tie controller to the off-grid controller.

This has the advantage of being a COTS solution you can just buy; though skill will be required to make it work, as is so with all off-grid stuff.  And it's not an option for "microinverter" solar panel setups.

### Legit battery system with "Dump" to grid

Alternately, assuming your solar panels are DC, you can build a "legit" battery/off-grid solar system, same as you would for a remote cabin.  Have the solar *charge controller* charge the battery, and hook up the water heater as a load driven off the battery (possibly through an inverter). The water heater would be fed exclusively from battery. It would draw normal currents, and would not need modification if used with an inverter.

You add some intelligence to control the water heater. When battery charge is above 90%*, the water heater inverter spins up and runs the water heater until battery charge drops to 60%*.  Then it shuts off and lets the battery recharge.  This repeats as long as there's solar.

* Varying cutoff percentage to suit the battery type.

Now, what do we do about the pesky utility grid? (ignore it, if it doesn't pay enough?) Well, that off-grid solar charge controller will have our old friend the Dump terminals, so this time, we direct Dump to the "Grid-Tie inverter".  Thus, it sells power to the utility only when it doesn't have anything better to do with it.

The battery can be any size you want or find practical; the size of the battery will only influence the cycle interval A very small battery might have the water heating running 30 seconds every 5 minutes; a larger battery perhaps 18 minutes every 3 hours.

Again, all the heavy lifting is being done by COTS equipment you can just buy; your only original craft will be the battery monitoring that turns on the water heater as the battery nears full.

Answer (score 2):

Water heater are essentially only a resistor that heats water. So I'd say you could probably just lower the voltage and it should work fine. One of the simplest way to do it is with a transformer.

If your water heater is 2000W @ 240VAC -> R=V^2/P-> R=28.8ohm V=sqrt(P R)=93VAC. So if you find a 90 ish volt AC transformer rated for the right current, it should work.

Comment: A 2 kW transformer would sound like an expensive solution, but yeah, should work. Don't forget that the resistance of a heater probably drastically increases with temperature – so, you need to take that into account in your R=V²/P calculation. A cold heater will draw more current than a hot one!

Comment: He wouldn't need a 2kW transformer! Only 400W ish. Even if resistance varies, power on water heater are not that accurate. It wouldn't make any significant difference.

Comment: That's the thing: when cold, the thing has lower resistance, so if you calculate your transformer for 400W, you might quickly be saturating the transformer core, because the heater never gets hot.

Comment: I won't make it an answer because it's not practical, but motor->flywheel->generator->PWM switch->water heater

Comment: why the "motor->flywheel->generator" detour in that, @user253751? What's the idea there?

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you just turn the water heater on and off, you'll be drawing from the power grid when it's on, and exporting to the power grid when it's off, so you put something in the way to smooth that out. As I said, silly idea, not practical.

Comment: ah, I get it. But honestly, a boiler's hot water reservoir would be a much easier storage of energy, compared to a flywheel. Simply only heat more water when there's an excess of power!

Comment: The resistance of a water heater does not drastically increase with temperature. The temperature coefficient of resistance of Nichrome is only 0.00017 per ° C and of Nichrome V only 0.00013 per ° C.

Answer (score 1):

Since a water heater is essentially a water-cooled incandescent light bulb, any dimmer for incandescent lighting (i.e., your average household dimmer, a.k.a. "forward phase dimmer" or "leading-edge dimmer") would do – given it is rated for light bulbs up to 2 kW. And it would be adjustable!

That should be commercially available, especially for stage light purposes, or can be built by yourself – though I'd say that if you're a beginner, it's *dangerous* to do.

> Of course I would couple it with a timer to draw only when power is available

I mean, the "proper" way here would be to get a sensor into the intermediate voltage that your solar power supply uses to generate the 220V AC from the DC your solar panel(s) produce, observe that voltage, and use the heater exactly as long as the observed voltage is above a given threshold. (Depending on the actual intermediate voltage, you might even opt to skip the whole AC-conversion and operate the heater as DC load directly attached to the internal voltage rail. But that would entail in-depth modifications.)

Point here: "timer" sounds like a bad solution. Instead, activate for as long as needed and power is available.

Comment: I'm not sure a dimmer would be safe since not many dimmer can handle 2000W. Also, if anybody was to touch this dimmer, it could compromise his power without his knowledge.

Comment: @Julien stage light dimmers for these powers are in the [50€ range](https://www.thomann.de/intl/stairville_ds2_rf_dmx_1ch_dimmer.htm). Yes, any machine is malfunctionable if abused, so that's really not an overly sensible concern.

Comment: Fair! I was thinking about wall mounted light dimmer! That would be a fair solution. It will drop your voltage to somewhat the right range and you can fine tune it if required! It's a neat solution!

Comment: Borderline nitpicking: Not all solar inverters are perfectly happy with that low power factor if they are made for export (PF=1) and not island operation (phase-cut loads). A single phase one should have enough capacitance to hold-up an entire half-wave at max load. If it works, it would be the cheapest option for OP, but it's not guaranteed success.

Comment: @winny uuuh that's right!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a solar diverter or solar router. There are plenty of [DIY](https://mk2pvrouter.co.uk/about.html) and commercial ones available.

These are based on:

- A way to measure excess solar production

Since you mention the grid I guess you're using a grid tied inverter. In this case you can either use a smartmeter that wants to talk via modbus, wifi, ethernet or anything else... or build one yourself with a microcontroller, a current transformer, and a voltage probe.

- A microcontroller to be the brains of the operation
- A way to control the dump load (aka water heater)

Low EMI way: get a three phase resistor for your heater.

Example: 3x800W 400V resistors means the resistor value is 200 ohms. Under 230VAW this makes 264W per resistor. You can also wire them in parallel or series/parallel to adjust power. This will draw a clean sine wave current, very little electronics, should be quite reliable.

High EMI way: use a triac dimmer. Simple and low tech, but the current drawn is not a sine wave which may cause trouble or weird noises with some appliances, and is probably not up to code.

Warning: Aliexpress dimmers are rated in Aliexpress amps, not Real Engineer Amps.

High tech way: use a pure sine wave dimmer, which is usually a rectifier followed by a high voltage buck regulator. This requires rather chunky filtering to draw a clean sinewave current from mains and not act as a wideband radio jammer.

Steampunk way: big iron autotransformer or variac.

Comment: The dimmer won't work. The problem is time. When the triac is gated off, all the solar will export to the utility. When the triac is gated on, all the solar will go to the water heater *and* it will draw the remainder from the utility.  And OP does not have *net metering*, that being the entire issue at hand!

Comment: Smartmeters measure and bill energy per-period. Otherwise it would not be possible to bill only active power and not reactive power. So yes indeed, oldskool phase cut dimming will absolutely work with non net metering. Makes a ton of noise though.

Comment: Citation needed on that, I think. I'm fairly sure they run two separate tallies for energy export and energy import, *within that period*.  If what you say is so, OP doesn't even need a dimmer, just a duty cycler that runs the water heater 6 seconds out of every minute (or 10% of the interval measured by the meter). That wouldn't make much noise.  One way to find out!

Comment: They do run separate counters for import and export. Energy is counted per-period, and at the end of the period, depending on sign, the period's energy is added to import counter or export counter. There is no other way to handle reactive power, which flows back and forth every period yet is not billed. If it worked as you say, within the period, then every X capacitor in the house would be metered as importing power during half the period then exporting power the other half!

Comment: If you use a duty cycler which passes complete periods, then it won't work, because on the periods it's on, it will import, and on the periods it's off, it will export, and these end up in two different counters that do not cancel. Pretty much everyone around here who does solar found out the hard way lol. If it averaged power over a reasonable duration like one second then it would be possible to use a duty cycler, which would be a better option, cheaper and cleaner.

Comment: OK well then nothing more to it, you can just have a contactor and a timer that runs your water heater for 30 seconds every 5 minutes. Heck I would just use a triac, and hold it gate full on for the entire 30 seconds.  (so no wave shaping).

Comment: No that won't work, if solar produces 500W and the load draws 1000W, on/off control like this will result in periods being billed for 500W import when on, and 500W export when off.